# Start to learn java and i have issue that i want to solve

Tags: java, comparison

i have bug that i cannot find, i have Class Point with method who receive other point and return true if my point is under the other poing and false if not, my problem is if my point x property is equal to other point x i still received true which is incorrect:

```
public class Point
{
    private double _x;
    private double _y;

    public Point(double x,double y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public boolean isAbove(Point other)
    {
        if (_x > other._x)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isUnder(Point other)
    {   
        if (isAbove(other))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use "x" as your vertical position? Normally you would use y for that.

Comment: if !isAbove(Point other), other is above. No need to isUnder method.

Comment: Small tip, off topic: You shouldn't use underscores or other creative ways to distinguish between fields and local variables. Common practice is to use keyword `this` like `this.x = x;` in constructor or any other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
public boolean isAbove(Point other)
{
    return (_x > other._x);
}

public boolean isUnder(Point other)
{   
    return (_x < other._x);
}
```

Why you had a bug: because the opposite of `A < B` is `A >= B`, not `A > B`.

Answer (score 1):

One point being under another isn't exactly the same as the opposite of one being above another — because points at the same level (their `x` being the same) are neither above nor below each other. So you need completely separate code for `isAbove` and `isUnder`:

```
public class Point
{
    private double _x;
    private double _y;

    public Point(double x,double y) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public boolean isAbove(Point other) {
        return (_x > other._x);
    }

    public boolean isUnder(Point other) {
        return (_x < other._x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isAbove(other))
```

Here you check if it is not Above, so it can be under or equal